# How to install Apache, MySQL, PHP and Composer via apt?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, curl, mysql, php

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I wish to install Apache, MySQL, PHP and Composer altogether via `apt`.

How to install Apache, MySQL, PHP and Composer via `apt`? Something like this?

```
apt install curl lamp-server^ php-curl composer
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. As per the man page, the install subcommand of apt accepts one or more packages:

```
       install, remove, purge (apt-get(8))
           Performs the requested action on one or more packages specified via regex(7), glob(7)
           or exact match.
```